# Is jasmine supposed to execute specs in the order they are declared or in a random order?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

un-comment the last spec.  All hell breaks loose...  why?

```
describe('test', function() {
  var index = 1;

  it('test 1', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(1);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 2', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(2);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 3', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(3);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 4', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(4);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 5', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(5);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 6', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(6);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 7', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(7);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 8', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(8);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 9', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(9);
    index++;
  });

  it('test 10', function() {
    expect(index).toBe(10);
    index++;
  });

  // it('test 11', function() {
  //   expect(index).toBe(11);
  //   index++;
  // });

});
```

thanks to @PWKad for pointing out this happens when there are more than 10 tests.

Comment: It's always ran in the declared order for me. My only suggestion is to cut down the real suite to the bare minimum that shows the issue and post that code in the question.

Comment: I don't have a huge amount of experience with jasmine, but with unit tests in general, you shouldn't expect them to run in any particular order - they're _unit_ tests after all.  If a particular test needs certain conditions, that should be in the set up/tear down of that test.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the issue is the functionality being tested is stateful and has an asynchronous API.  If I can't depend on the order specs are executed I'll end up with one deeply nested spec, which is ugly and doesn't reflect the parts of the API that are being tested.  I can live with it if someone knows for sure what jasmine's "expected" behavior is.  Up until now I've had the same experience as Michal Charemza.

Comment: I would expect that the framework authors would tell  you not to rely on the order of the tests as this is an implementation detail which may change with any release. I appreciate your comment above, but I suspect that relying on execution order will give you pain at the expense of not having 'ugly' tests. Usually your specs can have a 'background' where you can do your setup.

Comment: @SamHolder Agreed but there is something about having more than 10 tests that is triggering the random order.  Why 10+?

Comment: Running it with all 11 specs included at http://tryjasmine.com/ works fine for me.  Must be jasmine-version specific.  I agree it would be nice to know what's causing this, but I still wouldn't rely on the specific order of tests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, Jasmine executes the specs (it) in order. There was an issue from 2.3.0 to 2.3.3 with more than 10 specs. I hit the same issue in 2.3.3, the issue is fixed in 2.3.4.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/850

I just used 2.3.4 in place of 2.3.3 and my 15 tests finally passed.

Comment: This is now not the default, as @Anton says, Jasmine 3.x now run's tests in a random order by default.

Comment: So is there a way to turn it off in 3.x?

Comment: Is there any way to disable this default behavior ?

Answer (score 11):

Currently (v2.x) Jasmine runs tests in the order they are defined. However, there is a new (Oct 2015) option to run specs in a random order, which is still off by default. According to the project owner, in Jasmine 3.x it will be converted to be the default.

References:

- [Feature Discussion](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/171)
- [User Story in the Project Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/10606/stories/50579275)
- [Feature Pull Request](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/927)

Answer (score 3):

Here I am now in 2021, and indeed, the default setup via `npx jasmine init` sets random test order by default it seems.

Surely not what most developers would expect. (Not what I expected!)

To run in declared order, go into your `spec/support/jasmine.json` and set:

`"random": false`