# Can you customize the order of Jasmine Specs

Tags: testing, jasmine, automated-tests

It would be a pleasure if you could give Jasmine some kind of information, that it could use to define an order of the Specs. Is there a solution yet?

I could really need it to structure my files into different folders.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051693/is-jasmine-supposed-to-execute-specs-in-the-order-they-are-declared-or-in-a-rand