# Jasmine testing stateful service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to Jasmine testing and looking for a "best practice" for unit testing a stateful AngularJS service. Most tutorials I could find focus on test cases that run atomic calls to stateless services.

This matches nicely the Jasmine syntax

```js
it("should do something", function(){ expect(target.doSomething()).toBe... })
```

However, I found no obvious way to extend this pattern to a test case that involves multiple calls to one or several of the service's functions.

Let's imagine a service like this one:

```js
angular.module("someModule").factory("someService", function(){
  return { 
    enqueue: function(item){
      // Add item to some queue
    }
  }
});
```

For such a service, it makes sense to test that sequential calls to `enqueue()` process the items in the correct order. This involves writing a test case that calls `enqueue()` multiple times and checks the end result (which obviously cannot be achieved with a service as simple as the one above, but this is not the point...)

What doesn't work:

```js
describe("Some service", function(){
  // Initialization omitted for simplicity
  it("should accept the first call", function() { 
    expect(someService.enqueue(one)).toBe... // whatever is correct 
  });
  it("should accept the second call", function() { 
    expect(someService.enqueue(two)).toBe... // whatever is correct 
  });
  it("should process items in the correct order", function() { 
    // whatever can be used to test this
  });
});
```

The code above (which actually defines not one but three test cases) fails randomly as the three test cases are executed... just as randomly.

A poster in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051693/is-jasmine-supposed-to-execute-specs-in-the-order-they-are-declared-or-in-a-rand) suggested that splitting the code into several `describe` blocks would have these to be executed in the given order, but again this seems to be different from one Jasmine version to another (according to other posters in same thread). Moreover, executing suites and tests in a random order seems to be the intended way; even if it was possible, by setup, to override this behaviour, that would probably NOT be the right way to go.

Thus it seems that the only correct way to test a multi-call scenario is to make it ONE test case, like this:

```js
describe(("Some service", function(){
  // Initialization omitted for simplicity
  it("should work in my complex scenario", function(){
    expect(someService.enqueue(one)).toBe... // whatever is correct 
    expect(someService.enqueue(two)).toBe... // whatever is correct 
    expect(/* whatever is necessary to ensure the order is correct */);
  });
});
```

While technical-wise this seems the logical way to go (after all, a complex scenario is one test case not three), the Jasmine "description + code" pattern seems disturbed in this implementation as:

- There is no way to associate a message to each "substep" that can fail within the test case;
- The description for the single "it" is inevitably bulky, like in example above, to really say something useful about a complex scenario.

This makes me wonder whether this is the only correct solution (or ist it?) to this kind of testing needs. Again I am especially interested in "doing it the right way" rather than using some kind of hack that would make it work... where it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no code for this... Not sure it needs, I think you just need to adjust your expectations of your tests.

For the general rule of testing you don't really care how external dependencies handle the service, you can't control that.  You want to test what you think the expected results are going to be for your service.

For your example you'll just want to invoke the dependencies for your service and call the function and test what the expected results are from calling the `enqueue` function.  If it returns a promise, check success and error.  It calls an API check that and so on.

If you want to see how the external dependencies use your service, you'll test it on those dependencies tests.

For example you have a controller that invokes `enqueue`.  In the test you'll have to inject your provider (the service). And handle the expectations.